# Infinite nested elements in json file and How to get elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my JSON file:

```
layers :[
    {
      key: "1",
      title: "Computer Science",
      expanded: false,
      subLayer: [
        {
          key: "a",
          title: "Programming Language",
          expanded: false,
          subLayer: [
            {
              key: "a.1",
              title: "HTML",
              expanded: false,
              subLayer: [],
            },
            {
              key: "a.2",
              title: "CSS",
              expanded: false,
              subLayer: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
```

Images:

[image]

My question is: When I search Programming Language and Computer Science it appears but if you search for parts in subLayer elements such as HTML and CSS it doesn't appear or can't, why is that? And what needs to be improved from my coding? If I'm writing my code:

```
const filteredData = data.layers.filter((el) => {
    if (props.input === '') {
      return el
    }
    return el.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input) || el.subLayer.findIndex(x => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(props.input)) >= 0
})
```

Comment: Recursion is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You are only searching the top-most `subLayer`, which is `el.subLayer`. You need to search the nested `subLayer` also. This can be done recursively by looking at whether the current object's `title` includes your input, and if it doesn't you can check if [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) object in your `subLayer` includes the input in the title by recursively calling the search function:

```js
const layers = [{ key: "1", title: "Computer Science", expanded: false, subLayer: [{ key: "a", title: "Programming Language", expanded: false, subLayer: [{ key: "a.1", title: "HTML", expanded: false, subLayer: [], }, { key: "a.2", title: "CSS", expanded: false, subLayer: [], }, ], }, ], }, ];

const hasKeyword = (obj, keyword) => {
  return obj.title.toLowerCase().includes(keyword) || obj.subLayer.some(nested => hasKeyword(nested, keyword));
}

const search = (layers, keyword) => {
  return layers.filter(obj => hasKeyword(obj, keyword));
}

const res = search(layers, "css");
console.log(res);
```